# Mechanical Turk: get workers to complete all HITs in a batch

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am setting up an experiment on AMT. I have batches of 24 HITs. To keep my design balanced, I would like workers to be able to submit only once they completed all the HITs in a batch.

I am aware that a possible solution would be to create one HIT with 24 fields, but I would like to avoid that because I would like to keep the information for all the HITs separate.

Many thanks in advance,
Gabriella

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom qualification type for each batch of HITs. For each batch, find the worker that will complete the batch (either through some qualification test or manually), and award the qualification to that worker. Make sure the worker knows that they *must* complete all HITs in the batch in order for any of them to be accepted.

Now, the worker will be the only worker allowed to complete the batch, and you can do this for many many batches. However, it will require a bit of manual labor on your part.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. There's still no way to force the worker to complete all the HITs without using RejectAssignment. Further, what if the worker expires one of the HITs, do they deserve 23 rejections? One HIT with 24 questions is the only sane solution to this problem.

Comment: I think to say it doesn't solve anything is short-sighted. This solves the problem within the parameters that the user provided with a little extra work (contacting workers directly and making qualification tests). Provided that the worker wants to keep his/her data in some specific format such that the only way to conduct the HITs is to ask questions separately, this solves his/her problem. Obviously if a worker came across a technical snag such as an expiring HIT, special accommodations could be made, but this solution will work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. There is no way to force workers to submit all or none of the HITs in your batch. You could run **[RejectAssignment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_RejectAssignmentOperation.html)** to reject all the assignments of workers who submit <24 HITs, but this is very bad practice and will likely confuse and irritate workers.

> I am aware that a possible solution would be to create one HIT with 24 fields, but I would like to avoid that because I would like to keep the information for all the HITs separate.

I don't understand your reasons for not wanting to do it this way, but this is the only possible way. You could use JavaScript to only let them see one question at a time.